# Mysql select distinct and all columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have a table named `messages` with this set up:

```
`id` is the primary key.
`from` is the current user.
`to` is the receiver of the message.
`by` is the sender of the message.
`date` is the date of the message. its the time() function from php.
```

I want to write a statement to select all the unique `to` users. Also I want select the last message sent from `from` to `to` and order the by `date` `DESC`. I only have `from` variable to provide into the query. I have this code but it only works partially. It does not pull the latest message between the 2 users.

```
$get_messages = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT `id`, `from`, `to`, `by`, `date`, `message`, `seen` FROM `messages` GROUP BY `to` WHERE `from` = '$from' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Comment: As an aside, there are approximately 1m words in the english language. From this vast data set, the creators of MySQL have seen fit to reserve just (ca.) 230 of them. It really was tremendous bad luck then that in a pool of  5 words, you managed to pick three of them! ;-)

Comment: I am using `` which indicates it is the name of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the latest message from `to` user on the specified `from` user.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    messages a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  m.to, MAX(date) max_date
            FROM    messages m
            WHERE   m.from = @from
            GROUP   BY m.to
        ) b ON a.to = b.to
                AND a.date = b.max_date
WHERE   a.from = @from
ORDER   BY a.date DESC
```

Comment: This code worked like magic. I would of never guessed it. Thanks.